# Constant correctness

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, constants, const-iterator

In the printMessage if you access the vector of a constant class using the index it works fine, but not with the the iterator (*itr). If the iterator is declared as constant_iterator then it works fine.

Why?

In both cases I am reading the data and not modifying the vector. Can someone shed some light?

```
 #include <iostream> 
 #include <vector>
 #include <sstream>

 //Set this define to enable the block to compile.
 #define WILL_WORK 1
 #define WILL_NOT_WORK !WILL_WORK

 class TestMessage
 {
 public:
  TestMessage(){};
  typedef std::vector<int>  TestVec;
  typedef std::vector<int>::iterator TestItr;
  //The const iterator will work
  //typedef std::vector<uint32_t>::const_iterator TestItr;
  typedef std::vector<int>::size_type TestSize;
  TestVec m_testVector;
 };


 void printMessage(const TestMessage & tmessage)
 {
  std::ostringstream asciiMessage;

  asciiMessage << tmessage.m_testVector.size() << ",";

 #if WILL_NOT_WORK

 //This will not work
 // MS Visual Studio
 // error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from
 // 'std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>' to
 //     'std::_Vector_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>'
 // GCC 
 // error: conversion from
 // '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*,
 //                               std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >'
 // to non-scalar type
 // '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*,
 //                               std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >'
 // requested

  for (TestMessage::TestItr itr = tmessage.m_testVector.begin();
       itr != tmessage.m_testVector.end();
       ++itr)
  {
   asciiMessage << *itr;
  }

 #endif 

 #if WILL_WORK

  // This will work
  for(TestMessage::TestSize index = 0;
      index < tmessage.m_testVector.size();
      ++index)
  {
   asciiMessage << tmessage.m_testVector[index] << ",";
  }

 #endif

  asciiMessage << std::endl;

  std::cout << asciiMessage.str();
 }

 int main()
 {
  TestMessage message;
  message.m_testVector.push_back(10);
  message.m_testVector.push_back(20);
  message.m_testVector.push_back(30);
  message.m_testVector.push_back(40);
  printMessage(message);
  return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 different [] operators.  One const, one non-const.

The const-[] operator returns a const-reference and therefore the value at the index cannot be changed.

The normal iterator is non-const, meaning that the compiler might think that you could change the vector.  After all, you could pass the iterator to a function and then there is no way that the compiler can guarantee that the called function will not change the contents of the iterator/vector.

Therefore, there is also a const_iterator.  A const_iterator cannot be used to change the values in the vector.  This can be checked directly by the compiler.
If you pass a const_iterator to a function, the compiler can only assume that the called function behaves as it should be, namely not changing where the const_iterator is pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

An iterator (as opposed to const_iterator) on a vector of constant elements is not permitted. The iterator allows you to modify the vector element as well as read it. The compiler doesn't check to see whether you *do* modify it; it just prohibits using the iterator altogether. The const_iterator allows you to read const elements.

Answer (score 0):

Because a (non-const) iterator *would* allow you to modify the object, even if you don't do so. C++'s const enforcement is based purely on types -- to enforce based on what you do instead, it would have to have run-time monitoring of what you wrote to. It would take serious hardware support to do that without serious performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing your `TestMessage` object as a const reference to `printMessage`. Because of that, when you try to iterate over this object vector the compiler expects a `const_iterator`. Since it is not possible to convert it to a non-const iterator (it is not possible to automatically convert an `int*` to `const int*`, the underlying implementation of these iterators), the compilation will fail.

However, when you use `operator[]` with the vector, you get automatically a const reference to an `int` in the desired position, considering that this operator has an overloaded version to deal with constants.

If you change your declaration of `printMessage` to this `void printMessage(TestMessage & tmessage)`, it will compile. But you should **not** do that, since you would break const-correcteness, as your print message function clearly has no intent on modifying the `TestMessage` object passed as argument.